# Inconsistent Canvas Size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML5 canvas with height = 640. I expect the text with following style to be in the middle

```
top = 320px; 
position = 'absolute'
```

however this goes below the canvas, and

```
top = 140px;
```

looks like it is centered.

Screenshots: 
[140_640](https://prnt.sc/huqttv) | [320_640](https://prnt.sc/huqtpz)

What am I getting wrong? Should I try to use and do it in JS rather than CSS?

```
canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: account for the font size as well

Comment: IDs should be used only once. You have 2 elements with `#game-over`. Secondly, does the container have `position: relative`?

Comment: @sol you were right, for some reason I was spanning another #game-over in the div#game-over. Thanks!

Comment: Where are the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the text inside the canvas and use the canvas `textAlign` and  `fillText` to set the content and the position

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
ctx.textAlign = "center";     
ctx.fillText(canvas.textContent,430, 320);
```

```html
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="860" height="640">
<div>
<span>Game Over! You...</span>
</div></canvas>
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it is simple, but my specific problem occured as expalined by sol in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height of `<span id="game-over">` then just do this:

```
// Add this to your CSS for #game-over
// example span id="game-over" height of 200px;
#game-over
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

If you don't know the `<span id="game-over">` height then I would do this:

```
// Add this to your CSS for #game-over
#game-over
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
```

To check the height of the element and set the margin in `javascript`:

```
var gameOver = document.getElementById("game-over");
// get height
var heightOfText = gameOver.style.height;
// get half of height
heightOfText = parseInt(heightOfText)/2;
// set negative margin to center it
gameOver.style.marginTop = "-" + heightOfText.toString() + "px"
```